# How to get a json which is distinct of columns

Tags: sql, arrays, json, database, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database table and content is as below:

```
id | person_key | age | gender | email
1  | 1          | 25  | M      | test@mail.com
2  | 1          | 25  | M      | test_2@gmail.com
3  | 2          | 35  | F      | sample_2@gmail.com
4  | 1          | 25  | M      | test_3@gmail.com
```

I am looking for a way to get a json output as below:

```
person_key.   | json

    1         | {'age':25, 'gender':'M', 'email':['test@mail.com','test_2@gmail.com','test_3@gmail.com' ]} 
    2         | {'age':35, 'gender':'F', 'email':['sample_2@gmail.com' ]}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use aggegation and Postgres json functions:

```
select 
    person_key,
    json_build_object(
        'age', age,
        'gender', gender,
        'email', json_agg(email order by id)
    ) js
from mytable
group by person_key, age, gender
order by person_key
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5926b09a1f97490ec494b0a22490687a)**:

```
person_key | js                                                                                               
---------: | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 | {"age" : 25, "gender" : "M", "email" : ["test@mail.com", "test_2@gmail.com", "test_3@gmail.com"]}
         2 | {"age" : 35, "gender" : "F", "email" : ["sample_2@gmail.com"]}
```